# I want to create a summary in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Suppose i have the following raw data in excel spreadsheet:

[Name   ]  [ID    ]  [ Event ] 
[John   ]  [ 123  ]  [    A  ] 
[Peter  ]  [ 235  ]  [    B  ] 
[John   ]  [ 123  ]  [    C  ] 
[MAX    ]  [ 236  ]  [    D  ]

I want to create a summary like this:

[Name   ]  [ID    ]  [Event A   ]  [Event B    ]  [ Event C ]

John       [ 123   ] [  Yes     ]  [  No       ]  [   Yes   ] 
Peter      [ 235   ] [  No      ]  [  Yes      ]  [   No    ]

How could i generate the yes and no based on the raw data mentioned earlier? This means when John participates event A, it is marked yes else no. I can't seem to do a VLookUp with two conditions. Hope someone can help and advance thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into using Pivot Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like pivot tables, so I'd use one of those - though it might take some maneuvering to get it to say "yes" and "No".

Make a pivot table.  Put the Name and ID Fields as "row labels".  Make "Event" a column label.  Then put the "event" in the "values" field.  You'll end up with 1 = yes, blank = no.

Comment: To display Yes and No format the cells `"Yes";"Yes";"No"` This _displays_ `Yes` or `No` but the underlying data remains `1` or `0`

Answer (score 0):

Look into pivot tables in excel:

http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/01/27/pivot-table-tricks/
http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/chunkers/learn_to_use_pivot_tables_in_excel_2007_to_organize_data